# XSLT output distinct values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<LocatorInfo>
 <LocationAddr>
            <StreetNum>182</StreetNum>
            <StreetName>Eastern Avenue</StreetName>
            <City>Fall River</City>
            <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
            <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <GEOCode>
                <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
                <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
            </GEOCode>
        </LocationAddr>
        <LocationTimestamp>4/6/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
        <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
        <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
    </LocatorInfo>
<LocatorInfo>
    <LocationAddr>
      <StreetNum>285</StreetNum>
      <StreetName>Wastern Avenue</StreetName>
      <City>Ball River</City>
      <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
      <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <GEOCode>
        <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
      </GEOCode>
    </LocationAddr>
    <LocationTimestamp>4/7/2018 7:00:03 AM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
    <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
  </LocatorInfo>
<LocatorInfo>
    <LocationAddr>
      <StreetNum>182</StreetNum>
      <StreetName>Eastern Avenue</StreetName>
      <City>Fall River</City>
      <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
      <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <GEOCode>
        <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
      </GEOCode>
    </LocationAddr>
    <LocationTimestamp>4/7/2018 7:00:03 AM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
    <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
  </LocatorInfo>
```

I need to find a way to input each distinct address in one paragraph(StreetNum, StreetName, City, StateProv), basically just not output duplicates. And count the number of times each address has occured.

I have no idea how to tackle the problem.

Comment: do you know any language + library that you can use to parse xml?

Comment: I'm a complete newbie in xslt. I use Altova Xml Spy to parse.

Comment: ah, maybe start with a tutorial you find online - I found a few that walk through transforming xml to html, maybe try that!

Comment: I know how to transform xml into html. I just don't know how to do it in this particular case. I think I have to group StreeNum, StreetName, City and StateProv someway, otherwise the values get mangled together, I get all the street numbers one after the other. I need to extract the actual address on one row.

Comment: how does xslt store variable data? you can loop (<xsl:for-each>) but not sure how you'd make it distinct either, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe xml spy supports XSLT 2.0 and above so you should be able to use `xsl:for-each-group` to get the distinct groupings.

Try this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <Addresses>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="LocatorInfo/LocationAddr" group-by="string-join((StreetNum, StreetName, City, StateProv), '!')">
          <Address>
            <xsl:copy-of select="StreetNum, StreetName, City, StateProv" />
            <Count>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            </Count>
        </Address>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </Addresses>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```